# Start only one instance of MFC Dialog Based Application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have created a MFC Dialog Based application.

I started the application and it worked fine. Now, while it is running, I start the application again, and it starts another instance of it.

But, I do not want his behavior; If the application is already running, I want to prevent that new instances of it will be created.

Please, give me the code.

Comment: [Googling MFC Single Instance](http://jfgi.com?q=MFC+single+instance) reveals http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/singleinstancemfc.aspx

Comment: The easiest way is to check in your Main() if a process of the same name as your program is already running, and quit if it is. A google search will quickly find the relevant code, e.g. [This forum post should be suitable](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=457604)

Answer (score 10):

Try calling the following function in your main, before you call your application dialog class. If it returns False then then don't create your dialog and instead exit.

```
BOOL init()
{
   HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "mutexname");
   if(mutex == NULL)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
   { 
       /* You only need the message box if you wish to notify the user 
          that the process is running*/
       MessageBox("Another instance is already running.");
       return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
}
```

Ensure that the mutexname is unique, use VS to generate a GUID and use that in string form as the mutex name.

Comment: what is mutexname, i am not getting plz will you give the example

Comment: "mutexname" is a string value that you supply. You'll need to replace that in your actual code. The string needs to be as unique as possible. The easiest way is to use the GUID generator in Visual Studio to give you a GUID string e.g."{D07E6400-40D6-493a-8470-542A14102CB6}". Replace mutexname with that.

Comment: Ah I see that you're using VS 6 - I can't remember if that has a GUID generator, in which case use the one that I've supplied above.

Comment: humm it is difficult,bcz still i dont know in vc++ 6.0 how to use the GUID generator in VS to get the GUID string,

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using VS2008 and I can't remember whether VS6 has a tool for creating GUIDs. For me I have the option under the Tools menu to "Create GUID" I then selected the registry version and copied that to give me the string that I placed above.
You don't have to use a GUID for your mutexname, but its a surefire way of ensuring that your string is unique. If you wanted you could use any string e.g. "I love sausages with mashed potato and gravy" and it would still work until you came across someone else who liked sausages, mash and gravy. :)

Comment: I've edited my answer to show what to do with the return value of the function.

Comment: @smith, it doesn't need to be a GUID, you could just as easily use "plzsendmetehcodezkthxbye" :)

It just needs to be a string unlikely to be used by another application's mutex.

Comment: A quick Google search would have given you http://www.guidgenerator.com/ which is a site that generates as many GUIDs as you want. Or you can just use this one, that I just generated for you: `98bc9b99-a12f-4c61-b840-55e005f8b014`